# Tool to search text or content inside images in Windows 10

Tags: windows, ocr, file-search

I had seen [this](https://superuser.com/a/260838/1071605) answer. [Agent Ransack](https://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/) is used to search inside the files. Such as pdf, txt, doc and etc. But I have many images with texts, I want to search the keywords inside the images too. There is a feature in Gmail, while I search with a content, it also searches inside the images too and display the results. Is there any tools to search inside the images?

Answer (score 1):

see "Search for text in pictures" on Microsoft Store.
Click [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/search-for-text-in-pictures/9njnv7sh2413)!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/61824)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).